# Angular2 AOT Compilation failed; Resource file not found

Tags: angular, build, webpack, aot

To build my angular2 project with AOT, I run this command at first.

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/ngc -p ./src/
```

I receive some errors, but I can't resolve it,

```
Error: Compilation failed. Resource file not found: /Users/home_user/Devs/ds_dev_team/dmp-dashboard/src/public/main-web/app/styles/form
    at ModuleResolutionHostAdapter.readResource (/Users/home_user/Devs/ds_dev_team/dmp-dashboard/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/compiler_host.js:291:19)
    at CompilerHost.loadResource (/Users/home_user/Devs/ds_dev_team/dmp-dashboard/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/compiler_host.js:230:85)
    at Object.DirectiveNormalizer.get (/Users/home_user/Devs/ds_dev_team/dmp-dashboard/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:26374:111)
    at DirectiveNormalizer._fetch (/Users/home_user/Devs/ds_dev_team/dmp-dashboard/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13753:47)
    at /Users/home_user/Devs/ds_dev_team/dmp-dashboard/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13870:57
    at Array.map (native)
    at DirectiveNormalizer._loadMissingExternalStylesheets (/Users/home_user/Devs/ds_dev_team/dmp-dashboard/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13870:18)
    at /Users/1002719/Devs/ds_dev_team/dmp-dashboard/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13873:30
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:592:11)
```

I think It's happened because `form.scss` is lacked, so I handled it (remove or merged to other file, etc.) but It can be resolved.

.
.

Below is webpack config. 
these are all from https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

webpack.common.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const path = require('path');

// problem with copy-webpack-plugin
const AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin');
const NormalModuleReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin');
const ContextReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ContextReplacementPlugin');
const CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const HtmlElementsPlugin = require('./html-elements-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
const ngcWebpack = require('ngc-webpack');

// const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;
// if (ENV !== 'local' && ENV !== 'local-int' && ENV !== 'alpha' && ENV !== 'prod') {
//   throw new Error('NODE_ENV must be specified (local or local-int or alpha or prod)');
// }
const HMR = helpers.hasProcessFlag('hot');
const AOT = helpers.hasNpmFlag('aot');
const METADATA = {
  title: 'Dashboard',
  baseUrl: '/',
  isDevServer: helpers.isWebpackDevServer()
};

module.exports = function(options) {
  isProd = options.env === 'prod';
  return {
    entry: {
      'polyfills': './src/public/main-web/polyfills.browser.ts',
      'main': AOT ? './src/public/main-web/main.browser.aot.ts' : './src/public/main-web/main.browser.ts'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html'],
      alias: {
        '@angular/material': '@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',
      },
      modules: [helpers.root('./src/public/main-web'), helpers.root('node_modules')]
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: '@angularclass/hmr-loader',
              options: {
                pretty: !isProd,
                prod: isProd
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'ng-router-loader',
              options: {
                loader: 'async-import',
                genDir: 'compiled',
                aot: AOT
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
              options: {
                configFileName: 'tsconfig.webpack.json'
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'angular2-template-loader'
            }
          ],
          exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
        },
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          use: 'json-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
          exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
          exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: 'raw-loader',
          exclude: [helpers.root('src/public/views/index.html')]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
          use: 'file-loader'
        },
        { 
          test: /\.(eot|woff2?|svg|ttf)([\?]?.*)$/,
          use: 'file-loader'
        }
      ]
    },

    plugins: [
      new AssetsPlugin({
        path: helpers.root('src/dist'),
        filename: 'webpack-assets.json',
        prettyPrint: true
      }),
      new CheckerPlugin(),
      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'polyfills',
        chunks: ['polyfills']
      }),
      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        chunks: ['main'],
        minChunks: module => /node_modules/.test(module.resource)
      }),
      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['polyfills', 'vendor'].reverse()
      }),
      new ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)src(\\|\/)linker/,
        helpers.root('./src/public/main-web'),
        {
          // your Angular Async Route paths relative to this root directory
        }
      ),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {from: 'src/public/imgs', to: 'imgs'},
        {from: 'src/public/external-css', to: 'external-css'},
        {from: 'src/public/main-web/app/fonts', to: 'fonts'},
        {from: 'src/public/main-web/app/shared/error-page/error-page.html', to: 'errors/error.html'}
      ]),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/public/views/index.html',
        title: METADATA.title,
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
        metadata: METADATA,
        inject: 'head'
      }),
      new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
        defaultAttribute: 'defer'
      }),
      new LoaderOptionsPlugin({}),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)async/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)collection/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)errors/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/errors.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)lang/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)math/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/math.js')
      ),
      new ngcWebpack.NgcWebpackPlugin({
        disabled: !AOT,
        tsConfig: helpers.root('tsconfig.webpack.json'),
        resourceOverride: helpers.root('client-config/resource-override.js')
      })
    ],
    node: {
      global: true,
      crypto: 'empty',
      process: true,
      module: false,
      clearImmediate: false,
      setImmediate: false
    }
  }
};
```

webpack.prod.js

```
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const webpackMergeDll = webpackMerge.strategy({plugins: 'replace'});
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
const path = require('path');

/**
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
const AddAssetHtmlPlugin = require('add-asset-html-webpack-plugin');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const NamedModulesPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NamedModulesPlugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');
const NormalModuleReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin');
const OptimizeJsPlugin = require('optimize-js-plugin');

/**
 * Webpack Constants
 */
const ENV = process.env.ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = 'prod';
const HOST = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const HMR = helpers.hasProcessFlag('hot');
const METADATA = webpackMerge(commonConfig({env: ENV}).metadata, {
  host: HOST,
  port: PORT,
  ENV: ENV,
  HMR: HMR
});

const DllBundlesPlugin = require('webpack-dll-bundles-plugin').DllBundlesPlugin;

module.exports = function(options) {
  return webpackMerge(commonConfig({env: ENV}), {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/dist'),
      filename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js',
      sourceMapFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.map',
      chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].chunk.js'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
          include: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
          include: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        },
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new OptimizeJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: false
      }),
      new DefinePlugin({
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
        'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
        'process.env': {
          'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
          'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
          'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
        },
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV)
      }),
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        beautify: false, //prod
        output: {
          comments: false
        }, //prod
        mangle: {
          screw_ie8: true
        }, //prod
        compress: {
          screw_ie8: true,
          warnings: false,
          conditionals: true,
          unused: true,
          comparisons: true,
          sequences: true,
          dead_code: true,
          evaluate: true,
          if_return: true,
          join_vars: true,
          negate_iife: false // we need this for lazy v8
        },
      }),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /angular2-hmr/,
        helpers.root('config/empty.js')
      ),

      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /zone\.js(\\|\/)dist(\\|\/)long-stack-trace-zone/,
        helpers.root('config/empty.js')
      ),
      new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        minimize: true,
        debug: false,
        options: {

          /**
           * Html loader advanced options
           *
           * See: https://github.com/webpack/html-loader#advanced-options
           */
          // TODO: Need to workaround Angular 2's html syntax => #id [bind] (event) *ngFor
          htmlLoader: {
            minimize: true,
            removeAttributeQuotes: false,
            caseSensitive: true,
            customAttrSurround: [
              [/#/, /(?:)/],
              [/\*/, /(?:)/],
              [/\[?\(?/, /(?:)/]
            ],
            customAttrAssign: [/\)?\]?=/]
          },

        }
      })
    ],
    devServer: {
      port: METADATA.port,
      host: METADATA.host,
      historyApiFallback: true,
      watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
        poll: 1000
      },
      proxy: {
        '/dmp-idmpoc-api/user/v1/**': {
          target: 'https://idm-poc.skplanet.com',
          changeOrigin: true,
          secure: false
        },
        '/dmp-idmpoc-api/idm_poc/page/**': {
          target: 'https://idm-poc.skplanet.com',
          changeOrigin: true,
          secure: false
        },
        '/dmp-idmpoc-api/idm_poc/v1/**': {
          target: 'https://idm-poc.skplanet.com',
          changeOrigin: true,
          secure: true
        },
        '/dmp-idmpoc-api/dashboard/v1/**': {
          target: 'https://idm-poc.skplanet.com',
          changeOrigin: true,
          secure: true
        }
      }
    },
    node: {
      global: true,
      crypto: 'empty',
      process: false,
      module: false,
      clearImmediate: false,
      setImmediate: false
    }

  });
}
```